# Eclipse C++: Project builds but does not run

Tags: c++, eclipse

I included a custom header file, with a "test" function defined in it, as I am learning to include custom header files.

I was able to add the directory of the header file to the compiler "include" list, and Eclipse built the project fine.

However, when I try to run it, I get an error saying that it can't find the header file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

use `include` like this:

```
#include "../HeaderFolder/header.h"
```